# Package 'python3.8' has no installation candidate when trying to install nanovna-saver in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, python3

I once had the nanovna-saver executable working in version 18 something.
I upgraded Ubuntu to version 22.04. Since then the Nanaovna-saver exe does not work.

I am trying to reload nanovna-saver by following the instructions from [this link](https://github.com/NanoVNA-Saver/nanovna-saver/blob/main/docs/INSTALLATION.md). When I run the first command I get this error.

```
fkawee@fkawee-Satellite-C650:~$  sudo apt install python3.8 python3-pip
[sudo] password for fkawee: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Package 'python3.8' has no installation candidate
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted,  
or is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.8' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Simply follow the install instructions with the existing version of Python3. You got lucky: Had you succeeded in downgrading your existing Python3.10 to Python 3.8, you would have broken your system quite horribly.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions in https://github.com/NanoVNA-Saver/nanovna-saver/blob/main/docs/INSTALLATION.md are not correct for Ubuntu 22.04, because the default Python version in Ubuntu 22.04 is python3.10, not python3.8. Change the instructions for step 1 as follows.

1. Install python3.10, python3.10-venv and pip

   ```
   sudo apt install python3.10 python3.10-venv python3-pip
   python3 -m venv ~/.venv_nano
   . ~/.venv_nano/bin/activate
   pip install -U pip
   ```

The NanoVNA Saver application runs from a Python virtual environment, so to launch NanoVNA Saver you must activate its Python virtual environment first. Run `. ~/.venv_nano/bin/activate && cd nanovna-saver && python3 nanovna-saver.py` to activate the venv_nano python3.10 virtual environment and launch the NanoVNA Saver application from the nanovna-save directory in the venv_nano python3.10 virtual environment.

[image]
<sup>**NanoVNA Saver in Ubuntu 22.04**</sup>